# How To Refactor If-else Code Segment?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro

I'm developing win8(metro style) application with Html5-js-jquery. 
I have this code segment;

```
    GetBoutiqueDetail: function (boutiqueId, options) {
        if (IsUserLogin()) {
            //different job A
        } else {
            ShowLoginPanel(undefined);
        }
    },
    GetProductDetail: function (boutiqueId, productId, options) {
        if (IsUserLogin()) {
            //different job B
        } else {
            ShowLoginPanel(undefined);
        }
    },
    AddBasket: function (productId, productVariantId, quantity, options) {
        if (IsUserLogin()) {
            //different job C
        } else {
            ShowLoginPanel(undefined);
        }
    },....
```

.And ~20 functions should check if user login or not.
I should call functions like similar to "**Library.GetBoutiqueDetail();**"

So my question is simple, how can I refactor that code to remove these if-else sections ?

Comment: Why are those functions capitalized? They don't appear to be constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always wrap the common code into a higher-scope function, and have it invoked from the library functions - e.g:

```
//Higher scope:
function CheckForLogin(executionFunction)
{
   if(IsLogin) {
      executionFunction();
   } else {
      ShowLoginPanel(undefined);
   }
};


GetBoutiqueDetail: function (boutiqueId, options) {
    CheckForLogin(//different job A)
}
```

Passing in `different job 'N'` as an anonymous function to `CheckForLogin`

Answer (score 2):

How about an object map for this:

```
var objMap = {  
  "GetBoutiqueDetail":fnJobA,
  "GetProductDetail":fnJobB,
  "AddBasket":fnJobC}
  ....
}

if (loggedIn) {
  objMap[task]();
}
else {
  doLogin();
}
```

Comment: The example shown doesn't have any parameters. Hence the solution. Otherwise too, closures can be used.

Comment: The author of the problem does have parameters in the function `GetBoutiqueDetail` for example. I dont find the `job:fnJobA` obvious either? (I liked the map solution though, just looking for improvement, dont worry :D)

Comment: After taking a closer look, this doesnt really work. You should put an associative array (object) in stead of an array with objects. You can't use it as a map like this. `objMap[task]()` wouldn't work..

Comment: @EricG: Let me test this again. I have used it in past.

Comment: You should make it `var objMap = { "KeyA": funcA, "KeyB": funcB }` with `objMap[key]()` or else `var objMap = { "KeyA": { job: funcA }, "KeyB": { job: funcB } }` with `objMap[key].job()` (last one doesnt add anything though)

Comment: @EricG: Yes, it was a mistake. Just did a fiddle to test. Fixing the answer. http://jsbin.com/uxejep/1/watch

Comment: @EricG: Fixed it. It was a oversight while rushing to answer.

Comment: Best answer!.. I would refactor even more by proposing a ternary operator: `(loggedIn) ? objMap[task]() : doLogin();`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
checkLogin: function( action, actionArgs ) {

    if( IsLogin ) {

        return action.apply(this, actionArgs );
    }

    ShowLoginPanel();
},

GetBoutiqueDetail: function (boutiqueId, options) {

    //different job A
},
GetProductDetail: function (boutiqueId, productId, options) {

    //different job B
},
AddBasket: function (productId, productVariantId, quantity, options) {

    //different job C
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can return from a function to end it, so f.ex:

```
GetProductDetail: function (boutiqueId, productId, options) {
    if (!IsLogin) return ShowLoginPanel();
    // different job...
}
```

You will still have some repetitive code though. Another option is to define a higher level function. Something like:

```
var loginOrAction = function() {
    if (!IsLogin) return ShowLoginPanel();
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    Library[args.shift()].apply(Library, args);
}

loginOrAction('GetBoutiqueDetail', boutiqueId, options);
```

Comment: You're only skipping the `else`. But ok.

Answer (score -2):

use the ternary operator

```
(IsLogin) ? jobA() : ShowLoginPanel(undefined)
```

Comment: That doesnt unify the procedure (doesnt avoid code redundancy).

Comment: the question wasn't "code unification"... OP wanted to get rid of if / else -> ternary is useful in lots of situations.

Comment: The goal of getting rid of 'if-else' is not to avoid seeing the letters, but to avoid the duplicate code in all 20 functions. Hence, he might be satisfied with a standardized way of checking this. What do you think?

Comment: i agree completely. i just wanted to show the OP an alternative to if/else.

Comment: Alright. I dont argue that you strictly spoken answered the question, but people should not think that this is proper refactoring, unfortunately I'll therefore keep the downvote. Thanks for contributing :)